# How to integrate exist project with jsconfig

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image: Node error screenshot]
I was about to integrate `jsconfig.json` with my existing project for benefitting from its `baseurl` option. As the template showed by vs-code, I added a jsconfig.json to my client folder (which has its own node_modules, completely separated from server). But seems like it doesn't work. Meanwhile, it shows an error at the beginning  of the jsconfig file `client/node_modules/harmony-reflect/index' not found`, but when I `yarn add` harmony-reflect to client modules, the error still exists. Here is the code:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": ["./src/js/components/*"]
    },
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es2020"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Could you guys help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reopened editor and the problem was solved.

Comment: Me, too. I didn't even noticed when this was fixed automatically. Anyway, at least we can continue our work. Thank u bro. :)